# Is it possible to set default value to default field?

Tags: inputfield, default-value, developer-org

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_default_values.htm&language=en_US) says only about custom fields. And as I know I can not insert my custom js to default new-page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom list button with `Display in existing window without sidebar or header`

[image: Salesforce add custom button screen]

with link something like that:

`/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&opp3={!Account.Name}+" - "`

`opp3` it is the id of your desired default field that must be prefilled.

More info [here](http://www.interactiveties.com/b_pass_vars_url.php).